# Laravel Download file from storage and read contents from the response

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am running a unit test where I am testing file download for a storage and write to a local one.

However, when downloading the file, the contents are not as expected.

`$download->getContent()` returns false.

$download is an instance of  `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse`

```
 public function test_download_and_store_file(): void {
    $fakeFtpStorage = Storage::fake('ftp');

    // create file for download
    $writeDir     = '/some/fake/dir/test.txt';
    $fileContents = 'file content...';
    $this->assertTrue($fakeFtpStorage->put($writeDir, $fileContents));
    // check if content is correct
    $this->assertEquals($fileContents, $fakeFtpStorage->get($writeDir));
    $fakeFtpStorage->assertExists($writeDir);

    // download file from the ftp storage and check the content is correct
    $download = $fakeFtpStorage->download($writeDir);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(StreamedResponse::class, $download);
    $this->assertEquals($fileContents, $download->getContent()); //fails here

}
```

Comment: Your test makes no sense at all, you are literally testing the framework, not your code, so don't even waste time with it. Do this, explain in a comment here why you are trying to test a facade and file, and we may be able to guide you better

Comment: @matiaslauriti you are right, I am testing how the framework works which reflects how my code works as well. I want to download a file from the ftp server (FTP storage) and store that file in an other storage.

Comment: If you are not using your own code to do so, you will always test the framework. When you create the test, you need to fake having the file, or uploading it to your http route, then you can assert if the other storage got the file

Comment: I have dumped the $download variable and the content is null instead of `$fileContents` https://imgur.com/a/Diey2gB

Comment: anyway I created a different question to make my issue more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75666524/laravel-storage-download-get-content-always-returns-false